# Ajax условие

Tags: jquery

Подскажите как можно сделать так что бы функция

```
beforeSend: function(){ $("#stbody"+ID).animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);},
```

работала не только для id дива с видом stbody11 например, а для записи вида(причем в условии должно было быть что бы действие не только по ID шло а относилось к записи с соответствующем классом и id )

```
<div class="mess" id="12"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#stbody" + ID + ".mess") // $("#stbody12.mess")
```